# Hypergeometric identity

Tags: indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

I was trying to solve [this integral problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3070493/1618) and I noticed something that may be true

$$
\int((1-x^r)^{1/r}-x)^{2 n} \mathrm dx
=
\frac{1}{2 n+1}\sum _{j=1}^{2 n+1} (-1)^{j+1} x^j \binom{2 n+1}{j} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{j}{r},-\frac{-j+2 n+1}{r};\frac{j}{r}+1;x^r\right)
$$
for all $r>0, n\ge 1, n \in \mathbb Z$.

I did some numeric verification and this seems to be right. Any idea how to prove this?

Comment: how did you 'notice' this? It couldn't have been a guess... What did you do to come up with that?

Comment: Verify that
$$\frac d {dx} \left[ x^j
  \,{_2F_1} {\left( a, \frac j r; \frac j r + 1; x^r \right)}
 \right] =
j x^{j - 1} (1 - x^r)^{-a}.$$
Then you have a binomial expansion.

Comment: @clathratus I tried a few $n$ with Mathematica.